# why error "laravel 5.5 The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again" even after {{ csrf_field() }}

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-session

I already have {{ csrf_field() }} in form.
it works fine but after inactivity for some time create this error.
 why ?

Comment: You can set the `SESSION_LIFETIME` in your **.env** file, I believe the default is 120 minuts.

Comment: `inactivity for some time` Exactly how much ?

Comment: i did not measure by clock, but its around 30minutes am not sure about exact time

Comment: @thefallen yes, SESSION_LIFETIME=120 , can i set it lifetime ? or what is recommendation

Comment: do you have subdomain ?

Comment: @HasanTıngır no

Comment: @SaritaSharma can you run these commands `php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @HasanTıngır: what is use of these command , pleaseexplain

Comment: @SaritaSharma did it work ?

Comment: @HasanTıngır , no

Comment: @SaritaSharma it's for clearing your cached views, I thought cached view may be doesn't have csrf token

Comment: Could you refresh your browser cache ?  or try with another browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change lifetime of your session so that CSRF token could stick around longer. It is set up in `config/session.php` file, by default it's configured as:

```php
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
```

Meaning your session will persist for 120 minutes by default if not set otherwise in your `.env` file.

Comment: what is maximum limit, and where should I change ? .env or config/session.php orboth

Comment: @SaritaSharma this will set the session limit to 120 minutes (2 hours). Set this line in your session.php so the application defaults to 120 mins. If you need it to be different in different environments like production / development you can set in the .env

Comment: @SaritaSharma it's a good practice to change it in `.env` file if your config file is already set up to read `SESSION_LIFETIME` key (like in the example I provided). Maximum available lifetime is 35791394 which is approximately 68 or so years.